# mysql query fails only when we attempt to export to csv

Tags: mysql, csv

**Background Information:**

I'm trying to dump data from various tables to a csv file. 
When I run the actual query on it's own (without the command to write to csv file), I get the result set no problems.

**Problem:**

When I modify the query to write to a csv file, I get the error:

> ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'racktables.RackObject' references invalid
>   table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack
>   rights to use them

**Code**

Here's the code that does the select:

```
SELECT RackObject.id, RackObject.name, RackObject.label, RackObject.asset_no, RackObject.objtype_id, 
   (SELECT min(rack_id) FROM RackSpace WHERE object_id = RackObject.id) as rack_id, 
   (SELECT parent_entity_id AS rack_id FROM EntityLink WHERE child_entity_type='object' AND child_entity_id = RackObject.id AND parent_entity_type = 'rack' ORDER BY rack_id ASC LIMIT 1) as rack_id_2, 
   (SELECT parent_entity_id FROM EntityLink WHERE child_entity_type='object' AND child_entity_id = RackObject.id AND parent_entity_type = 'object' ORDER BY parent_entity_id ASC LIMIT 1) as container_id, 
   (SELECT name FROM RackObject WHERE id = container_id) as container_name, 
   (SELECT objtype_id FROM RackObject WHERE id = container_id) as container_objtype_id, RackObject.has_problems, RackObject.comment, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Port WHERE object_id = RackObject.id) as nports,    
   (SELECT domain_id FROM VLANSwitch WHERE object_id = id LIMIT 1) as 8021q_domain_id, 
   (SELECT template_id FROM VLANSwitch WHERE object_id = id LIMIT 1) as 8021q_template_id 
 FROM RackObject 
 ORDER BY RackObject.name;
```

And here's what the query looks like with the attempt to export to csv:

```
  mysql> SELECT RackObject.id, RackObject.name, RackObject.label, RackObject.asset_no, RackObject.objtype_id, 
 (SELECT min(rack_id) FROM RackSpace WHERE object_id = RackObject.id) as rack_id, 
 (SELECT parent_entity_id AS rack_id FROM EntityLink WHERE child_entity_type='object' AND child_entity_id = RackObject.id AND parent_entity_type = 'rack' ORDER BY rack_id ASC LIMIT 1) as rack_id_2, 
 (SELECT parent_entity_id FROM EntityLink WHERE child_entity_type='object' AND child_entity_id = RackObject.id AND parent_entity_type = 'object' ORDER BY parent_entity_id ASC LIMIT 1) as container_id, 
 (SELECT name FROM RackObject WHERE id = container_id) as container_name,  
 (SELECT objtype_id FROM RackObject WHERE id = container_id) as container_objtype_id, RackObject.has_problems, RackObject.comment, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Port WHERE object_id = RackObject.id) as nports, 
 (SELECT domain_id FROM VLANSwitch WHERE object_id = id LIMIT 1) as 8021q_domain_id, 
 (SELECT template_id FROM VLANSwitch WHERE object_id = id LIMIT 1) as 8021q_template_id 
 INTO OUTFILE '/var/log/objects.csv' 
 FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
 TERMINATED BY ';' 
 ESCAPED BY '"' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 FROM RackObject 
 ORDER BY RackObject.name;
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'racktables.RackObject' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
mysql>
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've googled the error message but so far, I haven't found anything that is relevant to my problem.

I'm also currently playing around with the csv dump options... removing one by one to see if it's a specific directive that i'm using that's causing the issues.

Finally, I'm planning to remove one by one, the various sub selects to see if it's a table level thing... but that seems odd to me, since I can run the query to screen no problems.

I've also tried this query... which works just fine:

```
mysql> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/var/log/objects.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM Object;
Query OK, 20079 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what racktables.RackObject looks like:

```
mysql> desc racktables.RackObject;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| name         | char(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| label        | char(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| objtype_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| asset_no     | char(64)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| has_problems | enum('yes','no') | NO   |     | no      |       |
| comment      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Usually the mysql user doesn't have rights to write to /var/ or anything except /tmp.  Why don't you try writing to /tmp folder ?

Comment: @prajeeshkumar He tried to select all and can write to this directory

Comment: @tuananh that is correct.  But just to satisfy prajeesh, I've also just tried dumping to /tmp.  I get the same error message.  :)

Comment: It might be caused by the order by: The order by requires the data to be written to a tmp object/table, which is then output to the csv file. Can you test without the order by RackObject.name

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen just removed the ORDER BY clause... But it still fails.

Comment: View 'racktables.RackObject' references invalid table(s): Can you share the view definition?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen please see EDIT 1 in my post

Comment: And the view definition (the error says it is a view: I would like to see the complete definition to see if something might cause this issue).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82855/discussion-between-dot-and-norbert-van-nobelen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the simplified scenarion with:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/var/log/objects.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ';'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM RackObject
ORDER BY RackObject.name;
```

It turns out that exporting data to an outfile from a view is not possible in MySQL. The query has to be rewritten to a version without a view.

Comment: Hi there. Just fyi.  not sure if dumping to csv from a view is supposed to "just work" in mariadb.  But I just tested it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, so also MariaDB can have an improvement there. I will keep it in mind.